# Substituting array values into a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to know if there's a way to make a substitution into an hash taking values from array.
This is my exemple:

```
%h = (
"a" => 'one,two,three',
"b" => 'four,five,six'
);

@a = "a: Letter", "b: Letter", "one: 1", "two: 2", "three: 3", "four: 4", "five: 5", "six: 6";
```

Final hash should be:

```
%h2 = (
"a" => 'one: 1,two: 2,three: 3',
"b" => 'four: 4,five: 5,six: 6'
);
```

I've tried many ways in order to get it: substitution, put the elements into an array.. But then I lost the elements order so my result was:

```
@a2 = "a: Letter", "b: Letter", "one: 1", "two: 2", "three: 3", "four: 4", "five: 5", "six: 6";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to translate you `@a` array into a more useful form, such as a hash of key value pairs.  Then you can process the values of `%h` to replace your words with more full information:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h = (
    "a" => 'one,two,three',
    "b" => 'four,five,six',
);

my @a = ("a: Letter", "b: Letter", "one: 1", "two: 2", "three: 3", "four: 4", "five: 5", "six: 6");

# Translate @a into key value pairs for later substitution
my %a = map {
    my ($key) = split ':';
    ($key => $_);
} @a;

# Proces values of %h
for (values %h) {
    s/(\w+)/$a{$1} or warn "Unknown key $1"/eg;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%h;
```

Outputs:

```
{ a => "one: 1,two: 2,three: 3", b => "four: 4,five: 5,six: 6" }
```

If you want to process both of keys and values, work on the flattened form of the hash and reassign it:

```
%h = map {s/(\w+)/$a{$1}/eg; $_} %h;
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "a: Letter" => "one: 1,two: 2,three: 3",
  "b: Letter" => "four: 4,five: 5,six: 6",
}
```

Comment: how can I have also 'a: Letter' instead of 'a' as a key? Thank you for your help.. what is the difference between data::dump and data::dumper?

Comment: To also translate the keys in `%h`, you could replace my final for loop with the following `%h = map {s/(\w+)/$a{$1}/eg; $_} %h;`.  As for [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), it just provides a simpler interface than `Data::Dumper`.  Read the [`history`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump#HISTORY) for more information on why it's useful.

Comment: Why can't I create an hash from an array if I write the array in this way?  @a = qw(c:d, e:f, g:h); and then.. foreach (@a) {
   ($key, $val) = split ":";
   $test{$key} = $val;
} ? It seems it doesn't recognize when the beginning and the end of the element array

Comment: You *could* do that, and maybe you should? However, given that you're trying to replace words with the full string `one: 1`, instead of just `1`, it makes sense to me to make the full string the string the value of the replacement hash, like I demonstrated.  If you know more about your data and goal, and you want to initialize to `'one' => '1'`, then go ahead and do so.  It could be more tightly coded as `my %test = map {split /:\s*/, $_, 2} @a;`

Comment: s/(\w+)/$a{$1} or warn "Unknown key $1"/eg;
If I have understood so here you're going to substitute the hash key (\w+) with the first occurrence of the hash %a.. is it right?

Comment: This phrase is wrong: *"with the first occurrence of the hash %a"*.  Hash keys are unique, so there is no first occurrence.  It is simply replacing the matched key with its value.  And if that key doesn't exist, a warning is printed.